# Git[Hub] - Using a Repository as a Dependency

Tags: git

I have a repository in GitHub that I'll call `ice-cream`. This repository has the *core* implementation of my ice cream. While I'm confident it's current fairly stable, I know that I may want to upgrade it down the road. Still, `ice-cream` serves as the basis for several other repositories like:

- French Vanilla
- Rocky Road
- Chocolate
- Peanut Butter
- Cookie Dough

When I clone any of these repositories, I also want to ensure a specific version of the `ice-cream` repository is cloned along with it.

How do I use one repository as a dependent of another in Git[Hub]?

Comment: What does "serves as the basis" mean, exactly? Is "Rocky Road" a fork of "ice-cream" at a specific commit, with additional commits added on top?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Rocky Road could be considered a fork I guess. It will start with a specific version of `ice-cream`. However, at that point, it will have it's own life. Meaning, if `ice-cream` updates to a new version, Rocky road will not automatically use that version.  Thus, if someone clones rocky road, they will have the original version of `ice-cream`.  It get's odd though because, I *might* want to merge a new version of `ice-cream` into rocky road after some testing. That's why a fork doesn't seem appropriate. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why doesn't it seem appropriate? That's exactly what forks are for. `ice-cream` repo would be the "upstream" repo for `rocky-road`. It is a standard operation to pull/merge latest upstream changes into your fork.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess I need to read up on forks better. I'm not a Git expert. I interpreted a fork another way.

Comment: @Dev Ever heard about git submodules? Looks like it's exactly what you want.